# SVG inline - default or inherited height

Tags: css, svg, responsive-design

please help me understand from where  element get 150px of height?

In my project, I want  element the same size as  content
but root svg element and visible svg get 150px of height (from out of space likely)

I make demo with similar conditions.
http://plnkr.co/edit/2EJiwZFSwjD2f4wrETiX?p=preview

```
<body>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="100%">
<symbol id="icon-smile" viewBox="0 0 1024 1024">
<rect fill="yellowgreen" width="100%" height="100%"/>
<path class="path1" d="M512 1024c282.77 0 512-229.23 512-512s-229.23-512-512-512-512 229.23-512 512 229.23 512 512 512zM512 96c229.75 0 416 186.25 416 416s-186.25 416-416 416-416-186.25-416-416 186.25-416 416-416zM256 320c0-35.346 28.654-64 64-64s64 28.654 64 64c0 35.346-28.654 64-64 64s-64-28.654-64-64zM640 320c0-35.346 28.654-64 64-64s64 28.654 64 64c0 35.346-28.654 64-64 64s-64-28.654-64-64zM704.098 627.26l82.328 49.396c-55.962 93.070-157.916 155.344-274.426 155.344s-218.464-62.274-274.426-155.344l82.328-49.396c39.174 65.148 110.542 108.74 192.098 108.74s152.924-43.592 192.098-108.74z"></path>
</symbol>
</svg> 
<div class=kx-rule>
<div class="cell col-md-3 col-sm-3">
 <svg class="u-icon" >
   <use xlink:href='#icon-smile'/>
</svg>  
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

I know I can size svg but I want understand it's behavior. I red that svg canvas infinite, but why it(viewport?) render with such height?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The svg element

```
<svg class="u-icon" >
```

Does not have either height/width attributes/styles or a viewBox so it gets the fallback height/width of [300](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#inline-replaced-width) x [150 px](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#inline-replaced-height) per the rules on replaced elements.

Comment: oh, thank you! I didn't know about replaced elements!